# merging from one feature branch to another after squashes

Tags: git, git-merge, squash, git-squash

My team likes to have a "clean" git history, and likes commits to be squashed before I request a code review. One aspect of this workflow I'm having trouble with:

I want to work on `feature-branch-2` (which depends on the stuff in `feature-branch-1`) while `feature-branch-1` is under review. So:

`git checkout -b feature-branch-2 feature-branch`

Add some commits to `feature-branch-2` while I work.

Code review comments come back, so I add some commits to `feature-branch-1` that respond to them. Then I squash those commits, and post again for review.

But now I've got a problem: How do I easily bring `feature-branch-2` up-to-date with the fixes to `feature-branch-1`? This would be an easy merge if I hadn't squashed `feature-branch-1`'s commits, but I'm not sure what's an easy workflow with the squashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are rewriting history by squashing, thereby removing the parent commit of your `feature-branch-2`, the only way I can think of is to rebase. After feature-branch-1 is updated you can do.

```
git checkout feature-branch-2
git rebase feature-branch-1
```